# binding a BehaviorSubject to [disabled] of a button

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component with a variable

```
refreshButtonEnabled$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

and a button

```
<button [disabled]="!refreshButtonEnabled$ | async">refresh</button>
```

Now I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
      The last overload gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'.

        <button [disabled]="!refreshButtonEnabled$ | async">refresh</button>
```

Could anyone please explain to me the error / what's wrong? I am new to Angular, so please bear with me.

Comment: Since not (`!`) has a higher precedence than the pipe (`|`) operator it is evaluated first, making the observable into a boolean. Use `[disabled]="(refreshButtonEnabled$ | async)===false"`

Comment: Thank you! That works! If you like you can post that as a regular answer. However, `[disabled]="!(refreshButtonEnabled$ | async)"` is shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since not (`!`) has a higher precedence than the pipe (`|`) operator it is evaluated first, making the observable into a `boolean`.

Use `[disabled]="(refreshButtonEnabled$ | async)===false"`.

Also, if you do `[disabled]="!(refreshButtonEnabled$ | async)"` angular will yell at you because of a potential pitfall, but if you know it can't happen you can happily ignore it :)